# Mysql: Determine size of user-created temp table

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, information-schema

I am creating a temp table in mysql. I would like to know the size of the table once it is created, but nothing appears for it using `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or in `information_schema.TABLES`. Is there any way to figure this out?

Two queries I have used in the past for something similar have been

```sql
SELECT
    table_name AS `Table`,
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
        table_schema = '<my schema>'
  AND table_name = <my table name>';
```

and

```sql
show table status like '<my table name>';
```

But both of these return empty results for my temp table.

Comment: Look in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SESSION_TEMP_TABLESPACES

Comment: Looks like that could do the trick, thanks!